# Metadata Updating in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, metadata

I am working in QGIS.

Is there a way you can lock the metadata so that no one can edit or change anything except me?

Comment: How are you editing your metadata?  How are you anticipating that others will try to edit your metadata?  If you are asking about metadata for shapefiles then that is stored as `*.xml` so the only way to lock it may be by using operating systems permissions.

Comment: What are you referring to as metadata, and what data format are you using?

Comment: @DPSSpatial data about my SHP such as author and descrptions. I want to add it to my SHP and lock it so that no one can actually edit it when I share the SHP. If you get what I mean? :/

Comment: Does my answer on this other question help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347041/viewing-metadata-in-qgis